# Why is the tikz picture not center aligned in ieeetran

Tags: ieeetran, tikz-qtree

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.* [.+ [.+ S1 S2 ] [.+ S3 S4 ] ]
[.S6 ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Service composition tree for Telecom Scenario}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I get the output as :

[image]

Why is the tree and the caption not center aligned?

Answer (score 1):

The nesting order is wrong; `center` should be *inside* `figure`, not the other way around.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.* [.+ [.+ S1 S2 ] [.+ S3 S4 ] ]
[.S6 ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Service composition tree for Telecom Scenario}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If no additional vertical spacing is wanted, it's better to use `\centering`, though:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.* [.+ [.+ S1 S2 ] [.+ S3 S4 ] ]
[.S6 ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Service composition tree for Telecom Scenario}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, `IEEEtran` with `journal` option doesn't center `figure` captions and this is a design choice (trying to override it for a jounal submission to IEEE doesn't make any sense since anyways the editors will revert any such change). If you want centered captions use another option for `IEEEtran` (such as conference, see example below) or another document class.

An example using the `conference` class option:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.* [.+ [.+ S1 S2 ] [.+ S3 S4 ] ]
[.S6 ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Service composition tree for Telecom Scenario}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You get centered captions for figures:

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo what about the caption? It is still not centered. That is the problem

Comment: @subhamsoni No, that's *not* a problem; it's a design choice. Read the `IEEEtran` HOW-TO document. `IEEEtran` with `journal` option doesn't center `figure` captions by design. If you want centered captions use another option for `IEEEtran` or another document class.

Comment: @subhamsoni You're welcome. I completed my answer with some example with the `conference` class option which allows centered figure captions.